# Specializing the template of std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl, c++17

I am trying to get an std::vector to hold fixed-length strings without introducing indirection through a wrapper class. My idea is to have a specialization of `std::vector` for my custom type that behaves like an `std::vector` to the outside, but uses its own storage layout. Kind of like `std::vector<bool>`.

I looked at "[Extending the namespace std](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)" and didn't find a reason why I shouldn't. Can I do the following, and if not, what type of hell am I facing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class FixedString {};

namespace std {
    template <>
    class vector<FixedString> {
    public:
        void push_back( FixedString&& value ) {
            std::cout << "Welcome to my vector. Let's play a game!" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    // here be more vector methods.
}

int main () {
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(int{});

    std::vector<FixedString> b;
    b.push_back(FixedString{});
}
```

Edit: I understand that there may be better ways of doing this and the discussion in the comments has helped me in understanding what's wrong with this. Still, I would like to understand if this is legal (even if undesirable) C++ code. People have hinted at [namespace.std] below, but I would like to understand which of the rules a fully specialized vector class would violate.

Comment: I almost thought so. Do you have any resource (maybe even the standard) for this? My search was inconclusive (or maybe I just understood it wrong).

Comment: What do you mean by "Fixed length strings"? Do you mean character arrays whose length is known at compile time? Also, if you actually want your vector class to work like std::vector, you'll have to overload *all* the methods std::vector provides.

Comment: @mrks - Checkout the section [namespace.std] of the standard

Comment: @JorgePerez Their length is not known at compile time. Otherwise, I would use std::array. I am aware that I'll have to overload all methods.

Comment: So why not simply use std:: string? And why would vector need to be specialised? Are you planning on specialising every other Standard Library container?

Comment: @StoryTeller I had that open before. Apparently I am not understanding it correctly. Which of the three point mentioned under "2 The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares" comes into play here? They all seem to talk about specializing members, not specializing entire classes.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Because both its size (40 B, because of Small String Optimization) and its indirection make it a bad choice for the performance we want. This is the same reason we want to avoid a wrapper around the `std::vector`. I don't care about specializing containers other than `vector`.

Comment: Why do you need to overload std::vector rather than just creating your own string class?

Comment: This doesn't explain why you think you need to specialise std::vector.

Comment: @mrks - Your specialization doesn't meat the requirements of `std::vector`, so it's a violation of paragraph 1, actually.

Comment: I can't create my own string class, because that class would have to have a fixed size. However, I don't know the size of the strings at compile time and don't want to initiate everyone accessing that vector for every possible length. By specializing vector, I hope to be able to write my own memory management for FixedLength (pretty much what `std::vector<bool>` does) without affecting the way `std::vector` looks from the outside.

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @StoryTeller What exactly are those requirements? From cppreference I gathered these which I believe I can fulfill: `Container, AllocatorAwareContainer, SequenceContainer , ContiguousContainer and ReversibleContainer. `

Comment: @mrks - As people have already said, writing a customised vector as you are is not allowed.   Or, more precisely, it causes program behaviour to be undefined (what you're doing is not one of the specified cases where specialising something in `std` is permitted).     In any event, you're barking up the wrong tree.   If you want customised memory management, create a custom allocator, then use that with a normal `std::vector<FixedString>`.   It's not overly difficult to find documentation that describes how to use custom allocators with standard containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule in [[namespace.std]](http://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#namespace.std-1.sentence-2) is:

> A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

So, two criteria: "depends on a user-defined type" (a better term, that hopefully will be adopted, is program-defined type) and "meets the standard library requirements for the original template." Your example meets the first criteria but breaks the second, so it's undefined behavior.

However, if you go ahead and fill in the rest of the requirements (see [[container.requirements]](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements) and [[sequence.reqmts]](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts) and [[vector]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector)) to meet the second criteria, then it'll be fine. But questionable. Just write your own container, principle of least surprise and all that. When people see `std::vector<T>` they assume it's actually a `std::vector`. `std::vector<bool>` is bad enough, don't add another one.

Comment: Would you say having MyVector which imports all `std::vector` methods in the default case and has a specialization for `FixedString` would be a better approach?

Comment: @mrks If `FixedString` is some special thing that needs its own separate container type, that seems like you should need your own separate container type.